# How to keep the zeros when I add price 1.500 in text box in asp.net using (c#) and save it the datatype for the price is decimal (20,3)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I add price 1.500 in text box and save it, it become 1.5 or 2.350 it's become 2.35 the datatype for the price is decimal (20,3) how can I  save the price with the zeros???

Comment: Zero has not significance this is why it is not saved, why you want to save zero?

Comment: Doesn't matter what you see. If it's decimal (20,3), that's what it will be stored as. Did you try storing something like 1.234?

Comment: In database, it will be stored as 2.35 no metter how many zeros at the end (2.350000000.... = 2.35). But when you want to show these values, you must format it in your way. Like `textBox.Text = (2.35).ToString("f3");`

Comment: @Adil I need it to convert digit number into word for example 1.500 it's convert it correct five hundred but when it 1.5 it return error

Comment: @feby, let the number saved without trailing zeros but add them when you show the number e.g using string.Format as you can see in the answer by ama1111

Comment: When you write 1.500 and 2.350, what does the point mean to you? A decimal separator, or a thousand separator?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the value as a float or a double then when you display it to the user you can decide how you want the value to be represented as a string. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float value = 1.5f;

    string text = string.Format("{0:0.000}", value);
    // text = "1.500"

}
```

Other numeric format strings can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just add formatting into standard `ToString()`; in your case you want *3 digits* after the decimal point so the corresponding format is `F3`:

```
  Double value = 2.350; 
  String result = value.ToString("F3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal value = Math.Round(value, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score -1):

Combinig these two responses , you can also write extension method which can serve the purpose.

```
 public enum FormatType
        {
            Default,
            TwoDecimal,
            ThreeDecimal,
            FourDecimal

        }
        public static string ToSpecificFormat(this decimal amount, FormatType formatType = FormatType.Default)
        {
            string fType=string.Empty;
            switch (formatType)
            {
                case FormatType.Default :
                    fType = "F2";
                    break;
                case FormatType.TwoDecimal :
                    fType = "F2";
                    break;
                case FormatType.ThreeDecimal:
                    fType = "F3";
                    break;
                case FormatType.FourDecimal:
                    fType = "F4";
                    break;

            }
           return amount.ToString(fType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


        }
```

You can modify this extension method to an extent you want for culture specific impementation to number format styles to currency, percentage and etc.